# Orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$ with conditions

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given are the linear subspaces
>   $$U=\operatorname{span}\{(1,0,-1,0),(1,-1,-3,-1) \}$$
>   and
>   $$V=\operatorname{span}\{(0,1,0,-1)\}^\perp$$
>   Find an orthonormal basis $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $U=\operatorname{span}\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $V=\operatorname{span}\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$.

I know how to find $a_1$ and $a_2$, but how do I find $a_3$? Can someone explain using a clear picture or something (or with an analogy in $\mathbb{R}^3$)? I don't even understand why this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible because $U \subset V$ by the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)

It is an algorithm that allows you from any base $(e_1, ..., e_n)$ of $\Bbb R^n$ to construct an orthonormal base $(a_1, ..., a_n)$ of $\Bbb R^n$ such that $\forall i \in \{1, ..., n\}$, $Vect(a_1, ..., a_i) = Vect(e_1, ..., e_i)$ and $\langle a_i, e_i \rangle \gt 0$ (such a base is uniquely defined).

Let :
$$e_1 = (1,0,-1,0) \\
e_2 = (1,-1,-3,-1) \\
e_3 = (1,0,0,0) \\
e_4 = (0,0,0,1)$$

Then $U = Vect(e_1, e_2)$, $V = Vect(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ and $\Bbb R^4 = Vect(e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4)$

By the Gram Schmidt process :
$$a_1 = {e_1\over\|e_1\|} = {\sqrt2\over2}(1,0,-1,0)\\
a_2 = {e_2 - {\langle e_2, a_1\rangle}a_1\over \|e_2 - {\langle e_2, a_1\rangle}a_1\|} = {1\over 2}(-1,-1,-1,-1)
$$
 and so on ...

$$
a_3 = {1\over2}(1,-1,1,-1)\\
a_4 = {\sqrt2\over2}(0,-1,0,1)
$$

**EDIT** As amd rightfully suggested, one can directly take $a_4 = {(0, 1,0,-1)\over\|(0, 1,0,-1)\|}$ since we know it is orthogonal to $V$

Comment: I might have chosen $e_4=(0,1,0-1)$ since we’re guaranteed that it’s not an element of $V$ without having to compare it to any of the other vectors involved. I think it would also be helpful to explain how you chose $e_3$.

Comment: I chose $(0,0,0,1)$ because it was the one I found most obvious, but you get the same result anyways (except you might get the opposite for $a_4$).